# Laravel - Selected value in form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have an edit account page, and I want to put the value in the database as selected :

```
@foreach($all_orga as $val)
    @if($val->id_organisme==13)
        <OPTION selected value="{{$val->id_organisme}}">{{$val->nom}}</OPTION>
    @else
        <OPTION value="{{$val->id_organisme}}">{{$val->nom}}</OPTION>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

This works fine as it displays the list but nothing is "selected", so I edited it using $compte->id_organisme, which is equal 3 in my test:

```
@foreach($all_orga as $val)
    @if($val->id_organisme == $compte->id_organisme)
        <OPTION selected value="{{$val->id_organisme}}">{{$val->nom}}</OPTION>
    @else
        <OPTION value="{{$val->id_organisme}}">{{$val->nom}}</OPTION>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

It still displays the list, but again, nothing "selected".

*Informations :*

```
dd($all_orga) 

    EQUALS

array:12 [▼
  0 => {#566 ▼
    +"id_organisme": 2
    +"nom": "Orga 1"
  }
  1 => {#515 ▶}
  2 => {#565 ▶}
  3 => {#564 ▶}
  4 => {#563 ▶}
  5 => {#562 ▶}
  6 => {#561 ▶}
  7 => {#560 ▶}
  8 => {#559 ▶}
  9 => {#558 ▶}
  10 => {#557 ▶}
  11 => {#556 ▶}
]
```

---

```
dd($compte->id_organisme)

    EQUALS

3
```

---

Here, the 3 value seems to be selected :

```
@foreach($all_orga as $val)
    @if($val->id_organisme == $compte->id_organisme)
        <OPTION selected value="{{$val->id_organisme}}">{{$val->nom}} {{$val->id_organisme}} {{$compte->id_organisme}}</OPTION>
    @else
        <OPTION value="{{$val->id_organisme}}">{{$val->nom}} {{$val->id_organisme}}</OPTION>

        @endif
    @endforeach

GIVES

Orga1 2
Orga2 3 3 (selected)
Orga3 4
Orga4 5
...
```

Comment: You'll use jquery on that matter.

Comment: I already have a list on this page, and the selected works perfectly.

Comment: So you want to display all data that is selected only?

Comment: nope, I want to add the select parameter to the "organisme" if it's the same as $compte->organisme

Comment: it seems like there is no $val->id_organisme which is equal to  $compte->id_organisme

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you let Laravel do the heavy lifting. Even though it's not part of the core Laravel has a nice form builder, which was moved to a separate project: [Laravel Collective](https://laravelcollective.com/). And there are quite a lot of other nice features that you would get by using it (e.g. [Form model binding](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#form-model-binding)).

Also, you might want to start using [collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections) instead of arrays. If I would write this in Laravel I would do it something along these lines:

```php
/**
 * Edit account action
 *
 * @file YourController
 */
public function editAccountAction() {
    return view('edit', [
        'compte'   => $compte,
        'all_orga' => collect($all_orga),
    ]);
}
```

And in your view:

```php
// use the collection's pluck method to build the array of options for the dropdown
{!! Form::select('name', $all_orga->pluck('id_organisme', 'nom'), $compte->id_organisme) !!}
```